# Why always the beginners?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

In the last few days I asked myself:

Why are there always those people who does downvote a question of beginners or, in the worst case, they close it?

Remember your beginning?

You tried everything to get better, but you were in front of a huge problem. What if there were only people which does say I won't help you because you're bad, you won't get better. What would you have done?

It's not that easy for beginner if they do not get any help of others.

It does not help if you downvote (or close) a question. How about you ask what his question is every beginner will answer your question!

So why are there still people which do downvote questions of the beginners?

Comment: In a related context, I found [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265415/how-can-i-start-a-discussion-critiquing-the-culture-of-stack-overflow/265422#265422) very good.

Comment: There's a place called [help] where a beginner can learn how to be a regular user.

Comment: Yet another person who doesn't get that **SO does not exist to teach people the basics of programming**. This site aims to be a high-quality knowledge repository, the goals is _not_ to "help beginners" or something like that.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because you didn't do your research. This has been discussed countless times here on Meta. We don't downvote because a user is a beginner. We downvote because the question is of **bad quality**. Not researched, not showing any effort to solve the problem themselves, etc. That has nothing to do with the level of experience the user might have.

Comment: @brasofilo Maybe not everyone is able to speak english fluently (im bad to) so they cannot ask high-leveled questions or understandable

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252234/3622940

Comment: I remember my beginning, I joined SO while I was still in school. I tried my best to research my problems and if I really didn't find it I came to SO and tried my best to ask a good question. From what I remember, most of them were well-received.

Comment: @Gentle: we really don't mind 'best effort english' either. Show us your efforts, what you did to try to solve the problem you are facing and we'll happily fix spelling and grammar mistakes. That's not (often) a reason to downvote someone.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because, as a _beginner_, you didn't put minimal effort into your question. I assume you didn't put together good content as well, and that's what downvotes are for. There's no grace period for beginners on SO, bad questions gets closed and bad content gets downvoted. You have to learn that the hard way!

Comment: In addition to @l4mpi, there are generally two types of beginners: those that care and those that don't. Unfortunately, there are many of those who do not seem to care. They do not follow the most basic rules about asking, they abandon their questions and in doing so, waste time of people trying to help others. Those are the ones that get heavily down-voted and closed.

Comment: I never downvote because of poorly written English, that's easy to fix.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261721/why-do-people-downvote-elementary-questions/261725#261725) is also worth reading in this context.

Comment: One thing I have realized that does seem to happen @Gentle is that a lot of beginners are not open to changing their ways.  They post a question, get downvoted, people comment on "what could be better done", and they just turn around saying "you downvote me! NOT NICE". I agree sometimes questions get heavily downvoted with no explanations, but as it has been pointed out, there is the help center, there is a popup to help you compose your first question. There are tools, some beginners just don't care about them, and I think some older members have stopped wanting to take everyone by the hand.

Comment: So you're basically asking, why do beginners ask such a lot of crap questions? It was already wondered a hundred of times.

Comment: This question was closed as dupe, but it is not ('why' versus 'how to prevent'). But since this one is primarily opinion based I'm not voting to reopen.

Answer (score 33):

Once again, we don't downvote and close questions *because they are from beginners*, we downvote and close questions *that are bad*. If a question happens to be from a beginner, we're not going to give it special treatment. They can use downvotes, close message, and comments as feedback to get better. There are plenty of other places on the Internet (and in the rest of the world) to learn the basics of programming. We don't have to hold people's hands here. That's not the goal of the site. Beginners are welcome if they ask and answer questions that are useful to the programming community. If they can't do that, then they need to start somewhere else to learn the basics. (Or just read all of the questions and answers that are already here.)