# Where can I speak out against user behaviour pattern? Is this the right forum?

Tags: discussion, flags, new-users, code-of-conduct

I've just noticed a behaviour on SO that I think creates a barrier to new users entering the community.

Where can I express my opinion to the Stack Overflow community and speak out against this sort of thing?

EDIT:

Please note this post is *not* intended to be my expression against the particular behaviour I mentioned. This post is a *question* about *where* such a post ought to be posted. You don't need me to give details about the behaviour in order to answer that question unless the particulars of the behaviour makes a difference to where one should express their opinion about it. Even then you don't need me to give the details of the behaviour, the answer could be of the form:

> If the behaviour is of type A then post about it in forum X, and
> If the behaviour is of type B then post in forum Y

Comment: Yes, this is the right place, but you would have to define that behavior you speak of so we can discuss it.

Comment: If you want to *complain*, then I don't think you'll get a good response anywhere. If you have specific complaints about specific users, you could raise a moderator flag on one of their posts, and explain the issue you see. *Discussion* and *complaint* are not synonyms.

Comment: Sigh, I see where this is going to end up :-P ...

Comment: Before posting your comp^H^H^H^Htopic for discussion, you probably want to look around here first. "Barriers to new users" is not a new idea. For starters, try [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758), [Why always the beginners?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270171), [Why do people downvote elementary questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261721), [What is the proper way to approach so as someone totally new to programming?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572)

Comment: and [How to encourage newbie programmers without enabling "hold my hand" comment streams?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255551)

Comment: Input on how to make SO friendlier and more welcoming is always appreciated. As has already been said, do check out the previous discussion though (if just to get a sense of the main arguments) and bear in mind that SO gets 8,000+ questions every day and relies on the time donated by relatively few volunteers. Any suggestion made must scale to that level

Comment: Given that you're calling this a "forum", are you sure its the community you have a complaint about, and this is not just because you do not understand what SO really is? (a Q&A site, not a site to provide support)? You can complain about the cookie monster teaching kids to consume large amounts of bad carbs and sugar, but that's just his design.

Comment: Sorry I should have used the word "suggestion" rather than "complaint". I'll fix it.

Comment: @TZHX raising a moderator flag in this case is not an option because the OP delete their question

Comment: You can still flag deleted posts.

Comment: @Gimbly I understand that SO is not there to provide support for new programmers - this has nothing to do with new progammers, it's about new SO users. I think if it's true that SO is designed in such a way that people are disqualified for being new to SO then perhaps it's doing itself harm, perhaps not but I'd like to see a discussion on that.

Comment: thanks @TZHX - I didn't know that! How do I find a deleted post?

Comment: You can't find them. But if you have it open, you can still flag it. You also won't be able to see it unless it's your own post or you have 10k rep.

Comment: @TZHX not much good to me then, but thanks anyway

Comment: well what do you want to say? you want to complain about a user, but don't know who they are and they've not got a single visible post on the site?

Comment: @TZHX no, I don't want to complain about a user. I want to suggest that SO users shouldn't behave in the way that many of them appear to do.

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi what way exactly? You need to give specifics if you want action. Saying "we're not nice to new users" will just give you a TON of responses as to why it's often appropriate to be this way. Come with specifics, that would be the only way to get pull on your suggestion here.... and come with PRECISE suggestions as well. Not just saying "the system is broken". You need to explain WHY the system is broken, what made you realize it, and what we could do to make it better. Saying "it's broken, fix it" will do squat

Comment: Question provides no details or description.

Comment: @jscs and probably, [When is Stack Overflow going to stop demonizing the quality-concerned users who have made the site a success?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366858/839601)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes, this is the right place, and am I duly warned that the ideas I'm mentioning have been hashed out thoroughly here already.